# Cannot implicitly convert 'int' to 'System.Reflection.BindingFlags'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Method

```
private static bool Properties(string a)
{
    BindingFlags bindingFlags = 84;
    PropertyInfo property = Bs._Game.GetType().GetProperty(a, bindingFlags);
    if (property != null)
    {
        return (bool)property.GetValue(Bs._Game, null);
    }
    FieldInfo field = Bs._Game.GetType().GetField(a, bindingFlags);
    return field != null && (bool)field.GetValue(Bs._Game);
}
```

The error is:

> Cannot implicitly convert 'int' to 'System.Reflection.BindingFlags'.
>   An  explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) before asking another question.

Comment: As the compiler indicates, this issue can be solved by adding the cast `BindingFlags bindingFlags = (BindingFlags)84;`. *Always* search for an answer yourself before posting a question here (you can copy and paste the error message into Google and see plenty of useful help with this already).

Comment: Much better than casting the number to an enum would be to use the actual enum values which makes the code much more legible (i.e. without looking it up what does 84 even mean?).

Answer (score 1):

You need an explicit cast:

```cs
BindingFlags bindingFlags = (BindingFlags)84;
```

Comment: I did do this, but it kinda broke all the GUIs in the class